# What is the anomaly in drawing of the Great Pyramid by National Geographic?

Tags: egypt, pyramids

In the chart below, which comes from [this page](http://www.ancient-wisdom.co.uk/Ghizaarchitecture.htm), there is a gray outline of another shaft and room behind the Queen's chamber description text. Does anyone know anything about this room or where it comes from?

It is interesting that it seems to extend from [the Arab archaeologist]'s entrance, however it seems to be separate. It isn't the grotto, because the grotto shaft is clearly marked.

[image: Diagram of the pyramid]

Comment: GAH! You have discovered one of the hidden chambers in the Great Pyramid !!!

Answer (score 9):

It is a shadow to show the vertical displacement of the Grand Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

That line vaguely details the original elevation of the hill upon which the Great Pyramid rests. There are theories that the original hill which used to hold the Sacred Well, whose remains are part of the Grotto, was terraced in order for the Pyramid to rest flat on the plateau. This same terraced hillside is shown in many plan views of the Pyramid, including the one below.

[image] *[Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/inside-the-great-pyramid-75164298/)*